# Accelerate the speed of selection in Random

Tags: simulation

Tossing 4 points on a circle at a time, and calculate the chance of all 4 points on the upper part of the circle.

[image: An illustration for this]

This is very simple by math:

$$\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^4 = 0.0625$$

But I want do a simulation in Mathematica.

```
po = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}}], 40000000];
f[m_, n_] := {m Cos[n], m Sin[n]};
Apply[f, po, {1}] // Partition[#, 4] & // 
   Select[#, AllTrue[Last /* GreaterEqualThan[0]]] & // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

it takes around 140 seconds for this code to finish.

**Is there a way to speed this up?**

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images of equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I only know a few about Tex. Could you edit it for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We get additional speed-up combining `RandomPoint` with `UnitStep`,`Total` and `Min` or `Count`:

```
n = 10^6;

SeedRandom[1];

RepeatedTiming[
 Total[Min /@ UnitStep[RandomPoint[Disk[], {n/4, 4}][[All, All, 2]]]]]
```

> ```
> {0.099, 15733}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1];

RepeatedTiming[
  Count[4] @ Total[UnitStep[RandomPoint[Disk[], {n/4, 4}][[All, All, 2]]], {2}]]
```

> ```
> {0.11, 15733}
> ```

versus the method from Bob Hanlon's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1];

RepeatedTiming[
 RandomPoint[Disk[], n] // Partition[#, 4] & // 
   Select[#, AllTrue[Last /* GreaterEqualThan[0]]] & // Length]
```

> ```
> {0.8295, 15733}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

It is more efficient to use [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) and `RandomPoint` distributes the points uniformly over the region.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[m_, n_] := {m Cos[n], m Sin[n]};

n = 80000;
```

To accurately compare the two methods, the point generation needs to be included in the timing.

```
RepeatedTiming[
 po = RandomVariate[
   UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}}], n];
 (Apply[f, po, {1}] // Partition[#, 4] & // 
      Select[#, AllTrue[Last /* GreaterEqualThan[0]]] & // Length)/(n/4) // N]

(* {0.160, 0.06455} *)
```

Note that the points cluster near the origin.

```
ListPlot[f @@@ po, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
RepeatedTiming[
 ((pp = RandomPoint[Disk[], n]) // Partition[#, 4] & // 
      Select[#, AllTrue[Last /* GreaterEqualThan[0]]] & // Length)/(n/4) // N]

(* {0.0423, 0.0619} *)

ListPlot[pp, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: `f[m_, n_] := {Sqrt[m] Cos[n], Sqrt[m] Sin[n]}` fixes the distribution problem and it only slows it down by a small fraction but `RandomPoint` is still faster. When generating $10^6$ points in a vectorized fashion, I found that it took 0.020 seconds versus 0.0256 with `RandomPoint`, so then they are about equivalent.

Comment: @C.E. why can adding `Sqrt` solve that problem? Can you explain?

Comment: @kile Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746409/395258).